# Finding the binary sub-tree that puts each element of a list into its own lowest order bucket

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

First, I have a list of numbers `'L'`, containing elements `'x'` such that `0 < 'x' <= 'M'` for all elements `'x'`.

Second, I have a binary tree constructed in the following manner:

```
1) Each node has three properties: 'min', 'max', and 'vals' (vals is a list of numbers).  
2) The root node has 'max'='M', 'min'=0, and 'vals'='L' (it contains all the numbers)
3) Each left child node has:
    max=(parent(max) + parent(min))/2
    min=parent(min)
4) Each right child node has:
    max=parent(max)
    min=(parent(max) + parent(min))/2
5) For each node, 'vals' is a list of numbers such that each element 'x' of
   'vals' is also an element of 'L' and satisfies
       min < x <= max
6) If a node has only one element in 'vals', then it has no children.  I.e., we are
   only looking for nodes for which 'vals' is non-empty.
```

I'm looking for an algorithm to find the smallest sub-tree that satisfies the above properties.  In other words, I'm trying to get a list of nodes such that each child-less node contains one - and only one - element in `'vals'`.

I'm almost able to brute-force it with perl using insanely baroque data structures, but I keep bumping up against the limits of my mental capacity to keep track of all the temporary variables I've used, so I'm asking for help.

It's even cooler if you know an efficient algorithm to do the above.

If you'd like to know what I'm trying to do, it's this: find the smallest covering for a discrete wavelet packet transform to uniquely separate each frequency of the standard even-tempered musical notes.  The trouble is that each iteration of the wavelet transform divides the frequency range it handles in half (hence the .../2 above defining the max and min), and the musical notes have frequencies which go up exponentially, so there's no obvious relationship between the two - not one I'm able to derive analytically (or experimentally, obviously, for that matter), anyway.

Since I'm really trying to find an algorithm so I can write a program, and since the problem is put in general terms, I didn't think it appropriate to put it in DSP.  If there were a general "algorithms" group, then I think it would be better there, but this seems to be the right group for algorithms in the absence of such.

Please let me know if I can clarify anything, or if you have any suggestions - even in the absence of a complete answer - any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After taking a break and two cups of coffee, I answered my own question.  Indexing below is done starting at 1, MATLAB-style...

```
L=[] // list of numbers to put in bins
sorted=[] // list of "good" nodes
nodes=[] // array of nodes to construct
sortedidx=1

nodes[1]={ min = 0, max = 22100, val = -1, lvl = 1, row = 1 }

for(j=1;j<=12;j++) { // 12 is a reasonable guess
  level=j+1
  row=1
  for(i=2^j;i<2^(j+1);i++) {
    if(i/2 == int(i/2)) { // even nodes are high-pass filters
      nodes[i]={ min = (nodes[i/2].min + nodes[i/2].max)/2,  // nodes[i/2] is parent
                 max = nodes[i/2].max,
                 val = -1,
                 lvl = level,
                 row = -1
               }
    } else { // odd nodes are lo-pass
      nodes[i]={ min = nodes[(i-1)/2].min,
                 max = (nodes[(i-1)/2].min+nodes[(i-1)/2].max)/2,
                 val = -1,
                 lvl = level,
                 row = -1
               }
    }
    temp=[] // array to count matching numbers
    tempidx=1
    Lidx=0
    for (k=1;k<=size(L);k++) {
      if (nodes[i].min < L[k] && L[k] <= nodes[i].max) {
        temp[tempidx++]=nodes[i]
        Lidx=k
      }
    }
    if (size(temp) == 1) {
      nodes[i].row = row++
      nodes[i].val = temp[1]
      delete L[Lidx]
      sorted[sortedidx++]=nodes[i]
    }
  }
}
```

Now array `sorted[]` contains exactly what I was looking for!

Hopefully this helps somebody else someday...